# onsenui modal data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Not sure if this is an Angular question, or an onsenui question, but here goes...

I would like to data bind an element in an onsenui modal as follows:

```
<ons-modal var="modalUpload">
    <ons-icon icon="cog" spin="true"></ons-icon>
    <div>
        <div>{{status}}</div>
    </div>
</ons-modal>

<ons-page ng-controller="someController">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>     
        </div>
        <div class="center">Some Section</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-row>
        <ons-col align="center">
            <div class="content-padded">
                <div>{{status}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-padded">
                <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="upload()">Submit</ons-button>
            </div>  
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

... the controller

```
function someController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.status = 'init';
    $scope.upload = function() {
        $scope.status('test test test');
        modalUpload.show();
    }
};
```

After calling $scope.upload(), $scope.status is updated.  There are two references to {{status}} in the view, one in the modal, and one in the page... When setting $scope.status, the reference in ons-page works as expected, but the reference in ons-modal does not.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be because of the modal is outside of the controller. How about trying putting it inside the controller as below:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="someController">
    <ons-modal var="modalUpload">
        <ons-icon icon="cog" spin="true"></ons-icon>
        <div>
            <div>{{status}}</div>
        </div>
    </ons-modal>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>     
        </div>
        <div class="center">Some Section</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-row>
        <ons-col align="center">
            <div class="content-padded">
                <div>{{status}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-padded">
                <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="upload()">Submit</ons-button>
            </div>  
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: that's way to obvious haha... cheers and I feel kind of stupid ;)

Comment: This solution works but has anyone experienced an issue where the modal will fail after nav.popPage(); is executed? Any way to resolve that?